# Parsing through JSON format

Tags: jquery, json

I'm having a hard time parsing through a JSON response I'm getting. It's formatted like this:

```
{
"kind": "fusiontables#sqlresponse",
"columns": [
"latitude",
"longitude",
 "geometry",
 "ID",
 "type"
],
"rows": [
[
40.92866,
-74.035957,
"40.92866,-74.035957",
"1",
"large_red"
],...
```

It's valid...I just left out the rest.

Here's the question, I'd like to get all of the "ID" and "type" and put it into an array. This is what I've tried:

```
var myData =$.getJSON('<JSON source URL is here>');
$(myData) , function(data) {
var ticks6 =[]
$.each(data, function (key, val) {
 var chartLabels= [val.ID, "" + val.type + ""];
 ticks6.push( chartLabels  );
});
};
```

I've used this code with differently formatted JSON and I can't figure out how to translate it to this format. I know I'm way off here, but I can't figure out where to go next.

Any insights would be helpful.

Comment: the javascript at the end makes no sense. `myData` will be a promise object, `$(myData)` doesn't make sense, etc.

Comment: @KevinB Well, that's the problem I have. I really don't know the syntax to use here to create the array. Can you give me any ideas?

Comment: I'd rather just point you to the [documentation.](http://api.jquery.com) That, or the [help site.](http://learn.jquery.com) Focus on receiving and logging the data to your console before you worry with processing it.

Comment: @KevinB I'm getting the data back for sure when I take a look in the console, but I've only seen it in another format (without the column names/types" at the top). Instead, I've seen it where each entry (row) has a column name before each value. So, I'm not sure how to handle it in this different format.

Comment: first, you have to change your code so that you can access the data in the code. The code you have given doesn't even come close.

Comment: @KevinB If I console.log "ticks6" the full object is in there, but just not in the format I want it. So, I'm accessing the data, but not parsing it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you work out getting access to the data, you can parse that structure using .map.

```
$.getJSON(url, function (data) {
    var ticks6 = data.rows.map(function (row) {
        return [row[0], row[4]];
    });
    console.log(ticks6);
});
```

Basically, the `data.rows` array is already in the format you want, only, it has more information than you're asking for. I simply used `.map` to filter it down to only the information you need.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed and worked perfectly. Sorry if my question wasn't totally clears. Appreciate you sticking with me.